# Is HTTPS secure?

Tags: ios, ssl, https

I'm developing a iPhone App that connects to a https:// link to authenticate the user.
From what I understood all traffic that goes to a server that has a private key on 256 bits is secured and cannot be caught so there is no need to encrypt the data again and it can be sent as plain text along the HTTPS connection.

After reading this blogpost:
http://wirewatcher.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/decrypting-ssl-traffic-with-wireshark-and-ways-to-prevent-it/

I don't understand how that traffic can be caught with Wireshark if it's secure.

**Edit:**
I've re-read the article and from what I understand you have to have access to the server's private key to do this.

What I don't understand is how this guy did it here because I don't think he had access to that.
http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/25/quizup-privacy-violations/
http://kylerichter.com/our-responsibility-as-developers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read carefully:

> [...] the output of this command is two files, **testkey.pem** (containing a
>   1024 bit RSA private key) and testcert.pem (containing a self signed
>   certificate)

And further down:

> Once SSL is selected, there’s an option on the right to enter an “RSA
>   keys list”. Enter something like this:
>
> 10.16.8.5,443,http,c:\openssl-win32\bin\testkey.pem
>
> You’ll need to edit the server IP address and **path to testkey.pem** as
>   appropriate.

And more:

> Protection of one’s private key is at the core of any system using
>   asymmetric keys. If your private key is compromised, the attacker can
>   either masquerade as you or they can attempt to carry out decryption
>   as outlined above.

Basically in the tutorial, the author is giving wireshark the **private key** to decrypt the trafic - **intentionally**. That private key MUST be kept secret on the server and shouldn't be accessible by anyone in a real life scenario. He gives some tips on enhancing security like using the Diffie-Hellman method of exchanging keys.

Bottom line: YES, it's secure.

Here are some nice videos that explain public key cryptography:
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB4D701646DAF0817

Comment: Indeed, it is secured alright.  Until Edward Snowden name shown up.

Comment: I added two additional links in which the poster explains that he managed to decrypt a ssl connection. From what I understand he did have the device but he did not have the sever private key. How can that be done?

Comment: HTTPS maybe has it's flaws. In the case of QuizUp it was a problem on their side, not the way the protocol works. Yes, there are speculations that NSA or other agencies can decrypt HTTPS traffic way faster than expected. There are also speculations that they introduced backdoors in cryptographic algorithms or even proposed their own algorithms. My guess is that you found a shitty article/app. For general security (disregarding other aspects - NSA) I highly recommend using HTTPS. You you are not sure if it's working, verify with Wireshark. You can also secure your server (and private key).

Answer (score 1):

Is your concern people snooping passwords and other user information, or figuring out the API and using your web service directly?

It's fairly simple to snoop HTTPS traffic on an iPhone, as long as you physically own the device (not some other MITM)

http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/monitoring-an-iphones-https-traffic-part-2

If you're concerned about people using your API, then yes you will need some kind of extra security on top of SSL. Let me know if this is the case and I'll suggest a couple of solutions for you.

Comment: I'm concerned about the MITM attack. I've linked to two additional articles that made me research the matter because from what I understood he used Wireshark to decrypt the ssl data that was sent from his device. As far as I know a MITM attack can be done by connecting to someone's router and tracking packets with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: How would you define 'secure'?
Security has many levels and aspects and EVERY type of security has 'holes'. Otherwise everything would be inaccessible (or inusable). Any type of security has advantages and penalties.

HTTPS 'just' adds an encryption layer on the (plain) HTTP layer. This means that all data over HTTPS will be encrypted between the sender and receiver, but.... The fact that the receiver can decrypt the data, basically means that anyone else can do it, why? Because it's just an encryption/decryption mechanism, so anyone having the right keys/info could perform the same operation. Therefor it's even more important to keep the private key real private, so the chance will be very small anyone will be able to hack your (SSL/TLS encrypted) communication.

Your understanding of https is basically correct, and https is secure. The linked post however is a very hacky way of accessing encrypted data, and he IS providing a PRIVATE key to the WireShark tool, which is basically why it works.

Comment: I've added two additional links where the poster managed to decrypt a SSL connection without having access to the private key from what I understand. My question and research started from the second article and I really don't understand how he done it.

Comment: It's not just an encryption/decryption mechanism. It also provides message integrity checking and peer authentication, and the latter allows the application to do peer authorization.

Answer (score -2):

By using The man-in-the-middle attack we can caught the traffic between the iPHone app and the network. Wireshark is a tool to capture network traffic

Comment: I know about MITM and about Wireshark. The problem here is about SSL traffic that can be decrypted.